# How to force the Visual Studio MSI Package to overwrite an updated file?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, windows-installer

this is my first post here.

I'm with a big problem here. I have a 1.0.0 application that installs an Access Database into the user's machine.
I have also a 1.0.1 version that needs to be released, and it has an new database file that i want to be installed overwriting the old file
.
Unfortunately, if the user does any update to the old file, the 1.0.1 version does not overwrite it anymore, and i did not find in any place how to force this file to be deleted or overwrited after being updated.

Can you guys help me with this?
Thanks and best regards

Comment: What you generally want to do is set that access DB as a [Companion File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367997(v=vs.85).aspx) to the main executable. How you do that depends on which installer tech you're using (but probably not doable if using a Visual Studio setup project).

Comment: As Damien said, the companion file method is recommended for your scenario. Setting the install mode from the command line is for some users cumbersome.

Comment: Are you still working on this?

Answer (score 0):

Oy vey, such a headache I had with this one.

Basically, you can try something like:

```
msiexec.exe /i yourmsi.msi REINSTALLMODE=omus
```

[here's some helpful information](http://www.packagedeploy.com/packaging-tips-tricks/always-overwrite-a-file-irrespective-of-msi-versioning-rules.html).

Honestly, we ended up using InstallShield, it was simpler and worth the money. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However i didn't find this REINSTALLMODE property, where can i find it??
It is default in Visual Studio or can be used with the Orca software?

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned Orca is your reply to [matt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10585277/15498), you can make the access database a [Companion File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367997%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) by editing the `Version` column in the [`File` table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368596%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> The installation state of a companion file depends not on its own file versioning information, but on the versioning of its companion parent. See the [File Versioning Rules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368599%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). To specify a companion file, the primary key of the companion parent in the [File table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368596%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) must be authored into the Version column of the record for the companion.